# How to differentiate between users using Basic Authentication

Tags: apache, basic-authentication

**Problem**
I have a website that uses Basic Authentication and has multiple different logins. I'd like a way to tell, using javascript, the username of the person currently logged in.

I checked the cookies and the basic Authentication credentials are not stored there.

**Stack**
I'm using Apache configured with a `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file so using the backend to tell the frontend which user is logged in is not an option.

**Goal**
The problem I'm trying to solve is really simple, I want my website to display the username of the person currently logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without a tiny bit of PHP. Javascript executes on the client and as you have already discovered, the username is not sent from the server so you will need something at the server end to send that userid.

Here is how:

As your page is generated at the server, it uses a small piece of PHP to add the username into your JavaScript and that's how JavaScript has it at the client to do with it what it needs.

Note, the userid wont change until the page is requested again by a different user, so it's not something that needs to be dynamic at the client side mid session.

PHP generates the page at server end when user logs in it includes it in the JavaScript code on the page. Where you want that name in your JavaScript you put it there using `<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']; ?>`. File extension will need to be .php for your file on the server that has your html and JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks! I added a file user.php and put in `<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']; ?>` then I made a get request to that file and it worked!

Comment: That's excellent. FYI, there is a lot you can get from the server this way just by changing the REMOTE_USER above to any of the others in the list at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. Comes in quite handy at times (-: